# Tkinter not registering some key events

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was working with Tkinter and specifically with binding Key Press & Release Events to functions but I ran into an issue.

I have function which appends the character pressed to a list so that I can check what all has been clicked later on, but it seems to work in some cases but not in others. For example, if I press the `a` key, then the `b` key, then the `j` key, it registers everything perfectly.

But when I try pressing the `n` key after `a` & `b`, it doesn't even register the key press.

[image]

Here is my code:

```py
def _on_key_press(self, e):
    self.last_key_pressed = e.char
    if e.char not in self.keys_down:
        self.keys_down.append(e.char)
        print(self.keys_down)
```

This function is bound to the toplevel window like `self.bind("<KeyPress>", self._on_key_press)`. Why does this behaviour occur? is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. It registers every key that I press.

Comment: Make sure your widget as focus before pressing keys

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's an issue with my system... that's really weird.  @Eric, I'm sure the widget is in focus because the other keys are working fine. It's only with combinations like a-b-n, or a-g-h, and maybe others.

Comment: @BhavyeMathur Any chance that another widget is also binding KeyPress ?

Comment: @EricMathieu I've checked all the other ones and it's only this one.

Comment: @BhavyeMathur can you share a bit more of your code ?

Comment: Hmm, so here's the whole code if you want it: https://github.com/BhavyeMathur/goopylib/blob/master/goopylib/GraphWin.py. But it's pretty long. The code I provided is located at line 349 & the binding to the function is at line 291.